# Ordering of floated elements

Tags: html, css

I've encountered an issue with floating an element that I don't quite understand. It's easier to show the problem than it is to explain, so I've created two examples to demonstrate how the output differs depending on what order you place elements that are floated.

Example #1

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="float-right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate metus velit, at mattis orci consectetur sit amet. Etiam tellus risus, ornare at tellus sit amet, suscipit aliquet sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed congue odio non massa vehicula convallis. Nullam maximus diam eu lectus pellentesque, et imperdiet erat fringilla.</p>
    </div>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://imageserver.moviepilot.com/watch-teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-season-2-episode-16-online-the-lonely-mutation-of-baxter-stockman-threatens-to-mutate-april-is-the-new-n.webp?width=640&height=479" title="TMNT!" alt="TMNT 90's logo" />
        <figcaption>TMNT logo from the 90's</figcaption>
    </figure>
</body>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 300px;
}
img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.float-right {
    float: right;
}
figure {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Output: http://jsfiddle.net/4yw8ga68/3/embedded/result/

Here a div containing a paragraph is floated right. This div is followed by a figure element containing an image and caption. In the output, you can see that the div is floated all the way to the right, and as a result, the image is placed at the top left of the page.

Example #2

HTML:

```
<body>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://imageserver.moviepilot.com/watch-teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-season-2-episode-16-online-the-lonely-mutation-of-baxter-stockman-threatens-to-mutate-april-is-the-new-n.webp?width=640&height=479" title="TMNT!" alt="TMNT 90's logo" />
        <figcaption>TMNT logo from the 90's</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <div class="float-right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate metus velit, at mattis orci consectetur sit amet. Etiam tellus risus, ornare at tellus sit amet, suscipit aliquet sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed congue odio non massa vehicula convallis. Nullam maximus diam eu lectus pellentesque, et imperdiet erat fringilla.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 300px;
}
img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.float-right {
    float: right;
}
figure {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Output: http://jsfiddle.net/4yw8ga68/5/embedded/result/

This code is the same as the first, only the floated div is placed after the figure and image. In this example, the div appears floated to the right, but is bumped down because of the image.

My question is, why is the output different in the second example? I would expect the output to be the same as the first example, considering the image and figure are only 200px wide and there is still plenty of room for the floated div to float all the way to the right and top of the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when the first element is floated, then whatever element that follows after it fills the space.

HOWEVER, if only the second element is floated then it does not have any effect on the first element, since it does not come after the second one.

If you want to achieve the same effect as the first code but keep your second HTML structure, then you need to add a float property to the `<figure>` element, as such:

```
figure {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4yw8ga68/6/